# Need to overlay two different heatmaps

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I am trying to overlay two different hexagonal heatplots, one which shows probability of a species introduction and another which shows whether or not the species already occupies that area. Essentially all hexagons already occupied should be black, whereas all other hexagons should display the probability of introduction.

Here's some clumsily made sample data.

```
df <- data.frame(latitude = rep(seq(1,10,1),10), 
                 longitude = rep(1:10, each=10),
                 already_there = rbinom(100,1,0.1), 
                 introduction_probability = rbinom(100,100,0.5)/100)
```

I've tried simply adding a geom_hex argument with the count limit set to 1 so that as soon as we get any occurrences inside a hexagon it is set to black.

```
ggplot(data=df) + 
  stat_summary_hex(aes(x = longitude, 
                      y = latitude,
                      z = introduction_probability),
                      binwidth = c(2,2)) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(mid="yellow", high="red",
                       breaks=seq(0,1,0.25),
                       limits=c(0,1)) +
  geom_hex(aes(x = longitude, 
                y = latitude,
                z = already_there),
            binwidth=c(2,2)) + 
  scale_fill_gradient2(mid="gray", high="black",
            breaks=seq(0,1,0.25), limits=c(0,1))
```

But of course the second fill command just overrides the first. Any ideas on how to solve this? Alternatives welcome. I tried writing a manual function to insert an ifelse clause to produce a different result if the hexagon was already occupied, but no luck.

Comment: Apologies, have added some sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the second `geom_hex` you need to `filter` the data to just include rows where it is present. If the number of presences are important, then `ggnewscale::new_scale_fill` can help.

```
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(data=df, aes(x = longitude, y = latitude)) + 
  stat_summary_hex(aes(z = introduction_probability), binwidth = c(2,2)) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(mid="yellow", high="red", breaks=seq(0,1,0.25), limits=c(0,1)) +
  geom_hex(data = filter(df, already_there == 1), binwidth=c(2,2), fill = "black")
```